# Aligning vertically center all content in a div based on another div without jquery or javascript

Tags: html, css

I have two div which exist in a container div of both in my html page and I want align all content exist in a sub div corresponding to contents of another div. Is it possible to do this by CSS rules only?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="subDiv1">
        some content here (with 400px height)
    </div>
    <div class="subDiv2">
        some content here (with 270px height)
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: First content is an image with variable height and second content is a label variable text length and I want align center both of them into same horizontal line vertically.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can you please provide some example code.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the same CSS for .subDiv1 and .subDiv2, why not just use the exact same CSS code for both of them?

Vertically aligning content within a div can be done with the following CSS:

```
.container {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: This rule will align horizontally center the content not vertically.

Comment: My bad. Wouldn't doing the same thing but replacing left and right with top and bottom work?

Comment: I tried that you are saying before but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
display: table;
width:100%;
}
.subDiv1,.subDiv2{
  padding: 10px;
  display: table-row;
}
.subDiv1{
  background-color:silver;
}
.subDiv2{
   background-color:#a7a5a5;
}
.container span {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="subDiv1">
        some content here <span>(with 400px height)</span>
    </div>
    <div class="subDiv2">
        some content here <span>(with 270px height)</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want align the image and label vertically center in a same horizontal  line but your code aligning them center in a same vertical line.

Comment: can have any view what you are trying to doing

Comment: at least draw me something on paper

Comment: I think I'm clear about what I'm asking. I want align the image and label in a same horizontal line as they are center of "container" div.

Comment: the dark gray area is supposed to be a image and "some content here" supposed to be a <label> tag